# Irrlicht Terrain Texture doesnt draw properly on Windows XP

Tags: c++, image, windows-xp, terrain, irrlicht

I have been developing a game with the Irrlicht library as part of one of my uni projects. However, when performance testing the Release build on a Windows XP PC my terrain does not seem to draw fully.[image: not working terrain]

I have tried many of the immediately logical possibilities, but none of them seem to affect it and it always cuts out in the same area. I have tried using a square texture, scaling it 1:1, 1:10, 1:20, etc. I have tried using images bigger than 1024x1024 and smaller, I have tried both pngs and jpegs, but to no success, I have tried using both OpenGL and DirectX. This is the terrain implementation:

```
ITerrainSceneNode *terrain = scnmgr->addTerrainSceneNode("../media/terrain-heightmap2.bmp", 0, -1, vector3df(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vector3df(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vector3df(20.0f, 4.4f, 20.0f), SColor(255, 255, 255, 255), 4, ETPS_9, 4);
if (terrain)
{
    terrain->setMaterialFlag(EMF_LIGHTING, false);
    terrain->setMaterialTexture(0, driver->getTexture("../media/grass.jpg"));
    terrain->setMaterialTexture(1, driver->getTexture("../media/detailmap3.jpg"));
    terrain->setMaterialType(EMT_DETAIL_MAP);
    terrain->scaleTexture(1.0f, 20.0f);
}
```

and this is what it looks like, when run on windows 7 (functioning as intended):
[image: functioning terrain]

Answer (score 0):

Update your graphics drivers in Windows XP if it's not done yet, then recompile Irrlicht in Windows XP platform.